# Call functions inside WebView with injectJavaScript

Tags: react-native

I've been looking for examples of injectJavaScript. On GitHub I found a few which, I guess for testing, do:

```
injectJavaScript={()=>'alert("Injected JS ")'}
```

But I can't make it work. I thought that perhaps I had to wait for the WebView to be loaded, but still no luck.

Here my test:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );

    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };
  }
  webviewDidLoad(){
    this.setState({loaded: true});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={ webview }
        injectJavaScript={ this.state.loaded ? ()=>'alert("Injected JS")' : null }
        onLoadEnd={ this.webviewDidLoad.bind(this) }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Is the only way to communicate to the WebView through strings and props? No way to communicate with WebView methods passing native javascript objects?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  WebView,
} from 'react-native';

let jsCode = `
    document.querySelector('#myContent').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
`;

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={localStyles.viroContainer}>

        <WebView
          source={{ html: "<h1 id='myContent'>Hello</h1>" }}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          ref={webview => {this.myWebview = webview;}} 
          injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
        />

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={localStyles.overlayButton}
          onPress={this.sendMessageToWebView2}
          underlayColor="transparent">
          <Text>Send message to WebView</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }

  sendMessageToWebView2 = () => {
    console.log(this.myWebview);
       console.log(this);
    this.myWebview.injectJavaScript(`
            (function () {
             document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
            })();
        `);
  };
}

var localStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  viroContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  overlayButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 110,
    height: 50,
    width: 150,
    paddingTop: 30,
    paddingBottom: 30,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#f0a0aa',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#000',
  },
});
```

Comment: You used `injectedJavascript` property instead of `injectJavascript`. Which means it runs only once.

Comment: Yes i know. On making the webview it executes it once. When i click the button, it will execute it one time each time you click it.
I edited the sendMessageToWebView2 function as in the meantime i managed to get it to finallu work for me. Im very happy.

Comment: Tried it in Expo and it kind of breaks: https://snack.expo.io/@nuthinking/webview-injectedjavascript
So injectJavaScript is in fact a method, not a property, right?

Comment: whoops, i use this webview import:

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview-messaging/WebView';

Comment: i'll try to look into it tomorrow because it's late now

Comment: Oke i got it!
Just copy this in your expo thing and it should work! good luck!
(dont forget to mark this as answer ;) )